# Fetch data from url in php not working in localhost

Tags: php, json, api, session, curl

i want to fetch data from a url https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD

so i write the following code

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));

$item =  $jsonData->items;
$date =  $jsonData->date;
$gold_price = $item[0]->xauPrice;
echo "Gold price on ".$date." is ".$gold_price;
  curl_close($curlSession);
```

But for some reason this is not working . Please check

> Notice: Trying to get property 'items' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'date' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'xauPrice' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 11

---

> from goldprice.org we are getting gold->USD->OZ = 1,275.67 .this value
>   we are outputing using the above code . But i need gold->USD->g=41.01
>   . Please check goldprice.org u will understand

Comment: Not working __how__?

Comment: i updated the question . Please check now

Comment: Dump `$jsonData`, dump `curl_exec($curlSession)`.

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/lv217ZqNqE7H9jX5wKd2Lg I ran it on an online ide and its working fine

Comment: could you please check this in localhost also

Comment: This can happen if the internet is not connected or you are blocked by a firewall. before accessing the item and date make sure the son response is parsed correctly by if(isset($jsonData->items) && isset($jsonData->date)){ // }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$output = curl_exec($curlSession);
$jsonData = json_decode($output);
var_dump($jsonData);
$item =  $jsonData->items;
$date =  $jsonData->date;
$gold_price = $item[0]->xauPrice;
echo "Gold price on ".$date." is ".$gold_price;
curl_close($curlSession);
```

You don't have:

```
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: good solution , but could you please help us to get the current price in gm

Comment: Is that a currency?

Comment: gold price in gram

Comment: How is it now? per kg? What conversion do you need?

Comment: from  https://goldprice.org/ we are getting gold->USD->OZ = 1,275.67 .this value we are outputing using the above code . But i need gold->USD->g=41.01 . Please check  https://goldprice.org/ u will understand

Comment: That information isn't in `API`, in `json` and I don't see any documentation on their site.

Comment: After you get the value convert it to g I don't know oz equal g by how much but it's always like this    $g = $value * 0.100 ;    0.100 is the number you use to convert like 1 kg = 1000g

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your response to the array and access the desired element

```
$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
```

replace with

```
$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession), true);
```

The parameter `true` will convert the object to array.

```
print_r($jsonData);

Array
(
 [ts] => 1555669932973
 [tsj] => 1555669926185
 [date] => Apr 19th 2019, 06:32:06 am NY
 [items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [curr] => USD
                [xauPrice] => 1275.67
                [xagPrice] => 14.905
                [chgXau] => 3.77
                [chgXag] => -0.032
                [pcXau] => 0.2964
                [pcXag] => -0.2142
                [xauClose] => 1271.9
                [xagClose] => 14.937
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD");
$jsonData = json_decode($json);
$items = $jsonData->items;
$item = $items[0];
$date =  $jsonData->date;
$gold_price = $item->xauPrice;

echo "Gold price on ".$date." is ".$gold_price;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Postman-Token: 67666a77-d99b-c8fb-f202-5ae0003cfe31"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$res = json_decode($response);
echo $res->date.' ';
$price = $res->items;
echo $price[0]->xauPrice;
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```